# lapply works over an array or a single element?

Tags: arrays, r, list, vector

I'm slightly confused as to whether lapply works on a list or on a vector. See two examples below

1. Here, the mean function is applied over an array of numbers, ie, 1 to 5

   ```
   x = list(a=1:5, b=rnorm(10))
   x

   #$a
   #[1] 1 2 3 4 5
   #
   #$b
   #[1] -0.57544290  0.51035240  0.43143241 -0.97971957 -0.99845378
   #[6]  0.77389008 -0.08464382  0.68420547  1.64793617 -0.39688809

   lapply(x,mean)
   #$a
   #[1] 3
   # 
   #$b
   #[1] 0.1012668
   ```
2. But here, the runif function is applied over each individual element of the array

   ```
   x = 1:4

   lapply(x,runif)
   #[[1]]
   #[1] 0.5914268

   #[[2]]
   #[1] 0.6762355 0.3072287

   #[[3]]
   #[1] 0.8439318 0.8488374 0.1158645

   #[[4]]
   #[1] 0.8519037 0.8384169 0.2894639 0.4066553
   ```

My question is, what exactly does lapply work on? an array or an individual element? And how does it choose  it correctly depending on the function?

Comment: `lapply` works over the first level of elements that constitute the object. In case 1), this is each `list` item, in 2) this is each value in the `vector`.

Comment: @thelatemail , thanks. I did not understand the term 'first level of elements'. Could you please explain?

Comment: To use an analogy, if I have 4 chocolate bars (`1:4`), lapply will work on each bar. If I have 2 boxes containing chocolate bars  (`list(1:2,3:4)`), lapply will work on each box.

Comment: `lapply` is (approximately)  `for(i in seq(length(x) ) ){ res[[names(x)[i] <- fun( x[[1]]) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lapply` will work on whatever is the highest level which defines the structure of the R object.

If I have 4 individual integers, `lapply` will work on each integer:

```
x <- 1:4

lapply(x, identity)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 3
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 4
```

If however I have a `list` of length==2 each containing 2 values, `lapply` will work on each list object.

```
x <- list(1:2,3:4)
lapply(x, identity)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4
```

Comment: (1.5 years later digging... :)) Perhaps, it'll be useful to note that `lapply` coerces with `as.list` before any manipulation and works on that structure; in case of "integer" coerces to "list" first and in case of "list" just uses the same structure.