# R Programming Lapply

Tags: r

```
attach(airquality)
s <- split(airquality, airquality$Month)
```

If I run

```
lapply(s, colMeans(s[,c("Ozone","Solar.R","Wind")]))
```

An error comes. It says incorrect number of dimensions.

```
lapply(airquality, function(x)colMeans(x))
```

Also shows same error.

```
lapply(s, function(x)colMeans(s[,"Ozone","Solar.R","Wind"])
```

This code works perfectly fine.

But:

```
 f<-function(x){
    colMeans(x[,c("Ozone","Solar.R","Wind")])}

 f(s) #error  incorrect dimensions

 class(s) # class of s is list

 f(airquality)  #gives mean of each column
```

Is `function()` creating dimensions? If it is then why `lapply` on `airquality` isn't working?

Comment: Could you please check your opening and closing brackets? It's a mess.

Comment: (1) `lapply(s, colMeans(s[,c("Ozone","Solar.R","Wind")` doesn't work because it's just wrong. See `?lapply`. (2) `lapply(airquality, function(x) colMeans(x))` throws an error because you're trying to calculate `colMeans` on vectors (the columns of `airquality` are coerced to vectors without dimensions). (3) `function` is not creating dimensions - in your working example, your function is applied to elements of the list `s`, each of which is a `data.frame` and hence amenable to having `colMeans` calculated.

Comment: To clarify, `lapply` applies a function to each element of `X`. Each element of `s` is a `data.frame`, while each element of `airquality` is a vector (the elements of a data.frame are its columns). To use `colMeans` you need columns.

Comment: Please don't mangle edits made to improve your question.

Comment: lapply uses list and colMeans uses data.frame the doubt I have is how is function(x) inth above command bridging the two data types

Comment: `lapply` is doing exactly what I said above. If you do `lapply(airquality, I)`, you might see more clearly what are the "elements" that `lapply` is iterating over. The function is applied to each of those elements. Now, would you expect to be able to use `colMeans` on any of those vectors? No. Now try `lapply(s, I)`. Applying `colMeans` to _those_ elements makes much more sense, since they're data.frames, which have columns. Note that `lapply` does not operate exclusively on lists, e.g. `lapply(1:10, sqrt)`. The `l` in `lapply` is because it _returns_ a list (compare to `sapply(1:10, sqrt)`).

Comment: Thanks for that help jbaums but I still did not understand why is   lapply(s, function(x)colMeans(s[,"Ozone","Solar.R","Wind"])) working and    lapply(s, colMeans(s[,c("Ozone","Solar.R","Wind")]))  not working?

Answer (score 4):

Your split function returns a list, but you are manipulating it like an array or data frame.

The error is coming from `s[,c("Ozone","Solar.R","Wind")]`, which can't be subsetted this way as it is a list. Try

```
s$`9`[,c("Ozone","Solar.R","Wind")]
```

and you will see that this works, as

```
s$`9`
```

is a dataframe.

In your first attempt, you are not suppling a function, but a function evaluated on s. As you can't manipulate s like above, calling a function on it also causes the same error, as the input to the function is problematic to begin with.

Your second attempt fails, because lapply is going to end up feeding each column one by one to the colMeans function, which expects two dimensional arrays (and you have given it one dimensional arrays)

The reason that the last call works is that the function

```
function(x)colMeans(x[,c("Ozone","Solar.R","Wind")])
```

can be called on each item of the list s as each item is a dataframe. The lapply function simply applies this to each item in that list.

```
lapply(s,function(x)colMeans(x[,c("Ozone","Solar.R","Wind")]))
```

is the correct way to approach this.

An alternative way would be with the by function

```
by(airquality[,c("Ozone","Solar.R","Wind")],airquality$Month,colMeans)
```

Comment: Also relevant to this discussion - [lapply works over an array or a single element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477768/lapply-works-over-an-array-or-a-single-element/27477951)